my custom module doesn't seem to have an affect
I've created my 1st module.  The purpose is to add the customer group name to the order email template.  I think that I didn't do something quite right and was hoping someone could look at my files to see where I may have messed up.  The files are stored in magento/app/code/KeystoneCandle/AddGroupEmail/, /etc and /Observer
registration.php
    <?php
 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'KeytoneCandle_AddGroupEmail',
    __DIR__
);

module.xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="KeystoneCandle_AddGroupEmail" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

Observer file AddGroupEmail.php
<?php

namespace KeystoneCandle\AddGroupEmail\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Group;

class AddCustomerGroupToOrderEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_order;
    protected $_group;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        Group $group
    ) {
        $this->_order = $order;
        $this->_group = $group;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerGroupId = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
        $customerGroup = $this->_group->load($customerGroupId);
        $customerGroupName = $customerGroup->getCustomerGroupCode();

        // You can do additional processing with the customer group if needed.

        $order->setData('customer_group_id', $customerGroupId);
        $order->setData('customer_group_name', $customerGroupName);
    }
}

Then in the email template I try to use these variables to show the customer group name and ID
{{var order.customer_group_name}} {{var order.customer_group_id}} 

I've run setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, setup:static-content:deploy -f, cache:flush/clean
The strange thing is that the
{{var order.customer_group_id}} 

variable pulls the customer group id even after I disable my module (and run all the previous commands) so I'm not sure if that variable needed the observer or not but I can't get any reaction from the customergroupname.  I'd appreciate any insights.  Thanks.

I already answered this question for you in your previous post.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/373826/99987

Sorry Infinri, I missed your answer on my other post some how but to add some info, I'm using the email template from Marketing - Communication - Email Templates, I created a new template based off of the Magento - New Order template and added the customergroup variables there.  So it is just sent when a customer places and order.  I do know what commands to run once I have the module set up.

Awesome, once I get time I'll update my answer if need be.

so my solution actually targets the order_new.html email template.  So my solution should work for you as well.  and should be a bit lighter weight and more efficient,

Given the extremly limited experience here. We will be using the Preference Override Method. We will be creating our own OrderSender class and we will be preferencing it in our di.xml
STEP 1 create custom class. app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Override/Order/Email/Sender/CustomOrderSender.php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Override\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;

class CustomOrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{
    protected $groupRepository;
    
    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        OrderIdentity $identityContainer,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Renderer $addressRenderer,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        OrderResource $orderResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository
    ) {
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        
        parent::__construct($templateContainer, $identityContainer, $senderBuilderFactory, $logger, $addressRenderer, $paymentHelper, $orderResource, $globalConfig, $eventManager);
    }
    
    /**
     * Prepare email template with variables
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {
        $customerGroup = $this->groupRepository->getById($order->getCustomerGroupId());
        
        $transport = [
            'order' => $order,
            'order_id' => $order->getId(),
            'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
            'store' => $order->getStore(),
            'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
            'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
            'created_at_formatted' => $order->getCreatedAtFormatted(2),
            'order_data' => [
                'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
                'is_not_virtual' => $order->getIsNotVirtual(),
                'email_customer_note' => $order->getEmailCustomerNote(),
                'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel(),
                'group_id' => $order->getCustomerGroupId(), // only add this if you need the group id
                'customer_group_name' => $customerGroup->getCode()
            ]
        ];
        $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

        /**
         * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
         */
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'email_order_set_template_vars_before',
            ['sender' => $this, 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
        );

        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

        parent::prepareTemplate($order);
    }
}

STEP 2 define preference override.
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Vendor\Module\Override\Order\Email\Sender\CustomOrderSender"/>
</config>

STEP 3
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean

Hi Infinri, I created the files you gave me, edited the namespace line, and added {{var order_data.customer_group_name}} to my email template (marketing - email templates).  But my test orders come through with an error... Error filtering template: Warning: Undefined array key "customer_group_name" in /home/keystone/dev2.keystonecandle.com/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/VariableResolver/StrictResolver.php on line 83

One of the things that can cause this is in your before plugin. If your logic for getting the customer group name fails or returns nothing then the order_data.customer_group_name will not be defined giving you this error. Please test your code.

Hi Infinri, I think that the issue is that I didn't add any "custom logic" to the plugin, I used the file as you had written it.  I don't know enough PHP to write anything substantial, I can sort of muddle my way through reading some of it to get a general idea of what is being said but can't write any (other than copying and pasting small snippets).  I also still have the AddGroupEmail in my Observer directory, I wasn't sure if your plugin was meant to be instead of that method or in addition to it.

@Pete If this is the case then you should hire a Magento Developer because it seems like you are just fishing for free work. Either way i will update my answer to something simple and easy for your situation.

@Pete answer has been updated. You do not need an Observer or a Plugin in. And you will still call the customer group on email as order_data.customer_group_name
Once it works please upvote the answer.

first of all I appreciate your help, yes, I was looking for help from someone who knows a lot more than me. I didn't foresee this being such a big deal since the group_id was easily added.  I figured that could be converted to the matching group_name with an if/than statement. That being said, I have deleted the Observer and Plugin directories, created the Sender directory and placed the PHP file there, overwrote my di.xml file with yours and ran the commands.  I still get the same error as above. I add the variable to my email template like this {{var order_data.customer_group_name}}

I think i missed a command. Sorry. Updated the STEP 3

I normally run that after setup:upgrade but since you didn't specify I thought maybe it wasn't required for this.  During the di:compile command it says this... In ClassReader.php line 57:
Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [  Keysto
neCandle\AddGroupEmail\Override\Order\Email\Sender\Template $templateContai
ner ] of KeystoneCandle\AddGroupEmail\Override\Order\Email\Sender\CustomOrd
erSender class
In GetParameterClassTrait.php line 34:
Class "KeystoneCandle\AddGroupEmail\Override\Order\Email\Sender\Template" d
oes not exist

I tried adding a Template directory in Sender and moved the CustomOrderSender.php file into that , re-ran setup:upgrade, di:compile but get the same error @ 5/9... changed it back to the original setup since that didn't work.

Why would you do that??? please refrain from doing anything not advised to do. The issue here is you added an extra directory to your path which means now you have to make sure all references to your customOrderSender need to be updated then you want to compile again.

Hi Infinri, That is what I did, I got rid of the Template dir, put the CustomOrderSender.php file back in Sender, re-ran setup:upgrade setup:di:compile (which is where the same error showed up).  I have the files set up as per your initial setup.  As to why I tried that, I am attempting to learn and figure out some things on my own so I don't have to be a hassle.  I feel bad to have to keep asking for help.

@Pete
Hey, please do have a look at the below given steps,

Check Module Registration
Verify module.xml
Run Magento Commands
Enable the Module
Check for Compilation Issues

By following the above steps, you should be able to diagnose that why your custom module is not having the desired effect and correct any issues.
Thank You!
